# Restricting a buffer to the output of a nodejs child process

Tags: node.js, buffer, spawn

I'm trying to execute a command line command(here: cat) from nodejs using the spawn command.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var cat = spawn('cat');
result = new Buffer(2048);
cat.stdout.on('data', function (data) 
 {
    data.copy(result);
 });
cat.on('exit', function (code) 
{
    console.log(result.toString());
});
cat.stdin.write(InBUFFER);
cat.stdin.end();
```

The output of the command seems to be somewhere in the Buffer, but the rest is outputted as well. Is there some kind of null character that I could use to determine when the output ends?

**Update:** To clarify things: There's a lot of random characters in the ouput and they seem to be part of the Buffer. I'm looking for a way to divide the useful output of the command line command from the rest of the buffer.

Comment: "The output of the command seems to be somewhere in the Buffer, but the rest is outputted as well." I've read that several times and I can't figure out what it means. The rest of what? Outputted by what?

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean the rest of the Buffer. It seems to be random crap. Similar to a not initialized variable. Output means the stuff thats send to the console by console.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you have inside InBUFFER, which you're not showing.

If you have a string in `InBUFFER`, for example `"test"`, the `result` will contain `test` followed by a lot of zeros, up to 2048 (the 0s will get converted to blank when `toString` is called).
If you have garbage inside `InBUFFER`, you'll get garbage as output. Maybe you're reading a file and not setting the character encoding properly.

Comment: If if fill the inBuffer with `InBUFFER = new Buffer("test");` my Output start with test and then continues with random digits and symbols. Example as above. I know that I could restrict it by the length, but that wouldn't work for a case('ls' for example) where I don't know the length of the result.

Comment: If if fill result by `result.fill(0);` then it works. But that doesn't look like the proper solution for this.

Comment: actually i think it is, since the buffer is probably not guaranteed to be filled with zeros (by default). Either that, or just pass in the length of the string: `result.toString('utf8', 0, InBUFFER.length)`

Comment: As the output can be variable, I ended up saving `data.length` in the stdout.on method and using that for cutting the result. Thanks for your help.